# Air flow or illusion

Tags: fluid-dynamics

If you have temperatures in the teens on the outside of a new single hung window in a house and temperatures of 70 degrees on the inside of the house and it feels like air is coming through the seals of the window is it actual air penetrating the seal or is it air flow caused by the pressure deference's between the cold air meeting the warm air giving the illusion that air is penetrating the seal? Is this possible? There is air flow. I tapped a piece of ribbon above the upper and lower window where the two windows seal together. The ribbon twirls around.

Answer (score 1):

Cold air outside cools the warm air inside. Cold air is denser and flows downward.